# How to use a common string to reduce garbage collection?

Tags: android, string, garbage-collection

I have an Android system where I am updating 32 TextView's every 0.5 seconds.

Initially I used a String that was declared in the Timer handler but I an now trying to use a single String that was declared in the class. I use String.format to set the text in a call to setText() on each TextView.

I am seeing a lot of garbage collection from the application every 2-3 seconds of around 500K and the GC shows a total time of around 50 to 100ms each time.

Single stepping the code I can see that the String has a different address each time it's used. This is different to what I have been used to with C/C++ where the string was fixed in memory.

Is there any option in Android coding to create a single common string that would get re-used each time I want to create the text for the view? I would like to reduce this heavy GC that I am currently seeing.

Comment: Well `Strings` are immutable, If you change something about a `String` a new `String` instance is created and the old one will be garbage collected. There is no way around that. This is the reason why classes like `StringBuilder` exist. But why do you want to prevent this anyway? Is it causing you problems?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problems as such. I just thought it would be nice to clean it up a little.

The code seems to be good and stable otherwise and I am seeing no sluggishness from its operation considering there is a lot going on in the background of this app. (luckily I don't have battery drain issues to deal with)

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with that. And while working with Strings you can't prevent it. I assume the garbage collector logs in the logcat bother you? Just filter them out, it's what I always do. But it's completely normal so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: OK thanks. I guess I am not used to seeing so many in the Logcat output as previous apps have not had to deal with updating the display so often and with so many TextViews as this apps does.